# In Palantir Foundry's Data Connection tool, what's the difference between the transaction type options?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

When setting up a file-based sync in Data Connection, I see there are a few different options for 'Transaction Type'. What's the difference between them? When might I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Foundry docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-integration/datasets/#transactions):

---

#### Transaction types

The way dataset files are modified in a transaction depends on the transaction type. There are four possible transaction types: `SNAPSHOT`, `APPEND`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`.

#### `SNAPSHOT`

A `SNAPSHOT` transaction replaces the current view of the dataset with a completely new set of files.

`SNAPSHOT` transactions are the simplest transaction type, and are the basis of [batch pipelines](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/pipeline-types/#batch).

#### `APPEND`

An `APPEND` transaction adds new files to the current dataset view.

An `APPEND` transaction cannot modify existing files in the current dataset view. If an `APPEND` transaction is opened and existing files are overwritten, then attempting to commit the transaction will fail.

`APPEND` transactions are the basis of [incremental pipelines](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/pipeline-types/#incremental). By only syncing new data into Foundry and only processing this new data throughout the pipeline, changes to large datasets can be processed end-to-end in a performant way. However, building and maintaining incremental pipelines comes with additional complexity. [Learn more about incremental pipelines.](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/incremental-overview/)

#### `UPDATE`

An `UPDATE` transaction, like an `APPEND`, adds new files to a dataset view, but may also overwrite the contents of existing files.

#### `DELETE`

A `DELETE` transaction removes files that are in the current dataset view.

Note that committing a `DELETE` transaction does not delete the underlying file from the backing file system—it simply removes the file reference from the dataset view.

In practice, `DELETE` transactions are mostly used to enable data retention workflows. By deleting files on a dataset based on a retention policy—typically based on the age of the file—data can be removed from Foundry, both to minimize storage costs and to comply with data governance requirements.

---

Data Connection doesn't let you create a sync with a `DELETE` transaction type, because a sync that purely deletes data doesn't really make sense! If you'd like to delete data from your sync'd dataset, you can use a SNAPSHOT transaction to do so, but note that previous versions of the dataset will still include those files.

You can combine an APPEND or UPDATE transaction type with [file-based sync filters](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-connection/filter-file-syncs/) to only ingest the newly changed files on each run of your sync.